# How to Generate Extent report with child tests for each method?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

I'm using Keyword driven framework to drive Test Execution with 3 classes.

1. Driver Script
2. Function Library
3. Apptest to run the Driverscript keywords method

All the test cases related steps mentioning in Master sheet of Excel...Here i'm able to generate Extent HTML Report but i want to generate child tests as a method name and include only those method test logs.

## I want achieve:

Test Case Name:
child tests:

1. Open Browser-Open Browser method related logs will come
2. `LoginApp` - Login related logs will come
3. Create Customer - Create Customer related logs will come

## Reporting Class:

```
public class Reporting {

public static ExtentReports extent;
public static ExtentHtmlReporter reporter;
public static ExtentTest test;


public static Object startTest(String testname, String testCategory, String description) {

    // creates a toggle for the given test, adds all log events under it
    test = extent.createTest(testname).assignCategory(testCategory).assignAuthor("Rajesh Kuchana");
    return test;
}

public static Object testLogs(String Logdetails) {
    // log(LogStatus, details)
    test.log(Status.INFO, Logdetails);
    return test;
}

public static Object testPassLogs(String Logdetails) {
    // log(LogStatus, details)
    test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(Logdetails, ExtentColor.GREEN));
    // test.log(Status.PASS, "<p style='" + pass + "'>" + Logdetails +
    // "</p>","<span class='success label'>Success</span>");
    return test;
}



public static Object testFailLogs(String Logdetails) {
    // log(LogStatus, details)
    test.log(Status.FAIL, Logdetails);
    return test;
}

public static Object testWarning(String logDetails) {
    test.log(Status.WARNING, logDetails);
    return test;

}

public static Object testSkip(String logDetails) {
    test.log(Status.SKIP, logDetails);
    return test;

}

public static Object testSkipLogs(String Logdetails) {
    // log(LogStatus, details)
    test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(Logdetails, ExtentColor.ORANGE));
    return test;
}

public static Object testErrorLogs(Exception e) {
    // log(LogStatus, details)
    test.log(Status.ERROR, new RuntimeException(e));
    return test;
}

public static Object testErrorLogs(AssertionError e) {
    // log(LogStatus, details)
    test.log(Status.FAIL, new RuntimeException(e));
    return test;
}

public static Object testReporter() throws Exception {
    FunctionLibrary.createDirectory();
    // Add reporter to extent report
    reporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Reports/" + "./"
            + FunctionLibrary.getLatestModifiedFolderName() + "/TestExecution.html");

    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(reporter);
    reporter.loadXMLConfig("TestInputs/extent-config.xml");
    reporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);

    return reporter;

}

public static Object extentSystemInfo() {

    try {
        // Add system info in extent
        extent.setSystemInfo("Operating System", System.getProperty("os.name"));
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation");
        extent.setSystemInfo("HostAddress", "QA");

        extent.setSystemInfo("Browser", PropertyFileUtil.getValueForKey("Browser"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return extent;
}

public static Object screenCapture(String logdetails, String imagepath) throws IOException {
    // report with snapshot
    test.log(Status.FAIL, logdetails, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(imagepath).build());
    return test;
}

public static Object passScreenCapture(String logdetails, String imagepath) throws IOException {
    // report with snapshot
    test.log(Status.PASS, logdetails, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(imagepath).build());
    return test;
}

public static Object infoScreenCapture(String logdetails, String imagepath) throws IOException {
    // report with snapshot
    test.log(Status.INFO, logdetails, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(imagepath).build());
    return test;
}

public static void flush() {
    // calling flush writes everything to the log file
    extent.flush();
}

public static Object testFailLogs(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    // get throwable exception in case test is fail
    test.log(Status.FAIL, iTestResult.getThrowable());
    return test;

}
```

}

In all the methods i'm using Reporting.testLogs("Enter value in text box");...etc

Comment: Please post the solution if you got it